# multiple data inputs to API through ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, frontend

I am new at coding and struggling to identify the problem

I am trying to give my API multiple data inputs that the user inserts through textarea. 
Everything works when I only give one input but when I try to add the code that will take the input from the second textarea it seems to stop all the code from working even the GET request. 
I need the data to be stringified and also to take the value of the text area or an input box.

Here is my code for the POST ajax request

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: API_URL,
        data:{JSON.stringify({"message": $('#msg').val()}, {"password": $('#pass').val()})},
        contentType: "application/json",

        success: function(data){
            location.reload();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check the `JSON.stringify()` method

You may want to do

```
JSON.stringify({"message": $('#msg').val(), "password": $('#pass').val()});
```

See [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)